# Can't insert rows in SQLite database in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to insert a couple of rows in a table in SQLite data base, I include this part of code in the main activity class as follows:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private TextView mTextMessage;

    Intent intent1;

    private DrawerLayout d;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle a;

    TabLayout tab;

    ViewPager vp;

    ViewPagerAdapter vpa;

    GridLayout mainGrid;

    DBAdapter db;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        insertSchools();

        d = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
        a= new ActionBarDrawerToggle(MainActivity.this,d,R.string.open,R.string.close);



        d.addDrawerListener(a);
        a.syncState();

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        intent1= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MapsActivity.class);

       //NavigationView view = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.n);

        mainGrid = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainGrid);

        //Set Event
        setSingleEvent(mainGrid);
        //setToggleEvent(mainGrid);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if(a.onOptionsItemSelected(item)){

                   return  true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();

        if(id == R.id.item1){

            startActivity(intent1);

        }

        if(id==R.id.item2){

            Toast.makeText(this,"رأيك يهمنا",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }




        if(id==R.id.item5){

            Toast.makeText(this,"حول التطبيق",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


        return false;
    }


    private void setToggleEvent(GridLayout mainGrid) {
        //Loop all child item of Main Grid
        for (int i = 0; i < mainGrid.getChildCount(); i++) {
            //You can see , all child item is CardView , so we just cast object to CardView
            final CardView cardView = (CardView) mainGrid.getChildAt(i);


            cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (cardView.getCardBackgroundColor().getDefaultColor() == -1) {
                        //Change background color
                        cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF6F00"));
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "State : True", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    } else {
                        //Change background color
                        cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "State : False", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private void setSingleEvent(GridLayout mainGrid) {
        //Loop all child item of Main Grid
        for (int i = 0; i < mainGrid.getChildCount(); i++) {
            //You can see , all child item is CardView , so we just cast object to CardView
            CardView cardView = (CardView) mainGrid.getChildAt(i);
            final int finalI = i;
            cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    if(finalI==0) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ListOfSchoolsPublic.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }

                    else if(finalI==1){

                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ListOfPrivateSchools.class);
                        startActivity(intent);

                    }

                }
            });
        }
    }


    /////////////////////////////INSERT SCHOOLS//////////////////////////

    public  void insertSchools(){

        //SCHOOL-1
        openDB();
        db.insertSchool("مدرسة دار المعرفة","0797417018 - 0790889165","Math - Science",2009,"الأول - السابع","عن طريق مستودع التربية","جيدة جدا","مختبر حاسوب - مختبر علوم","480 - 550","اربد/مجمع الشيخ خليل/حي النزهة",35.85542,"خاصة",32.54845);
        closeDB();
        //SCHOOL-2
        openDB();
        db.insertSchool("مدرسة الروم الكاثوليك","07272881","فرنسي",1951,"بستان - ثاني ثانوي","الشراء من مستودع التربية","ممتازة","مختبر حاسوب - مختبر علوم - مكتبة - فرقة فن","روضة / 500 | الاول - ثاني ثنوي / 1100","اربد/شارع الحصن/بجانب اسواق مكة",35.85155,"خاصة",32.55172);
        closeDB();
        //SCHOOL-3
        openDB();
        db.insertSchool("مدرسة النوار بنت مالك ","لا يوجد","لا يوجد",1970,"لا يوجد","لا يوجد","لا يوجد","لا يوجد","لا يوجد","لا يوجد",35.85391,"حكومية",32.54843);
        closeDB();
        //SCHOOL-4
        openDB();
        db.insertSchool("مدرسة زبيدة بنت جعفر الأساسية","لا يوجد","لا يوجد",1970,"الثالث - السابع","لا يوجد","جيدة","لا يوجد","لا يوجد","لا يوجد",35.85316,"خاصة",32.54871);
        closeDB();
        //SCHOOL-5
        openDB();
        db.insertSchool("أكاديمية الفرح","027250551 - 0796550752","الغاز عربية للصف الاول - كراسة كتابة وخط - مصطلحات علمية باللغة الانجليزية - Math - Science - منهاج تعليمي الكتروني للرياضيات والعلوم والانجليزي من الصف الخامس للصف التاسع",1994,"الروضة - ثاني ثانوي","لا يوجد","لا يوجد","مختبر حاسوب","اول - سادس / 600 | سابع - تاسع / 700 | عاشر / 750 | اول ثانوي - ثاني ثانوي / 900 | الروضة / 450","اربد/الحي الجنوبي/شمال جامعة اليرموك/جنوب شرق اشارة الاسكان",35.85199,"خاصة",32.54356);
        closeDB();
        //SCHOOL-6
        openDB();
        db.insertSchool("مدرسة جمانة الثانوية للبنات","لا يوجد","لا يوجد",1970,"لا يوجد","لا يوجد","لا يوجد","لا يوجد","لا يوجد","لا يوجد",35.85352,"خاصة",32.53322);
        closeDB();

        //SCHOOL-7
        openDB();
        db.insertSchool("روضة ومدرسة ابن النفيس","لا يوجد","لا يوجد",1970,"لا يوجد","لا يوجد","لا يوجد","لا يوجد","لا يوجد","لا يوجد",35.85050,"حكومية",32.54680);
        closeDB();

        //SCHOOL-8
        openDB();
        db.insertSchool("مدرسة البحرينية","0772062317","لا يوجد",1970,"الأول - العاشر","لا يوجد","جيدة جدا","مختبر علوم - مختبر حاسوب1 - مختبر حاسوب2 - حضانة - حديقة","لا يوجد","اربد/الحي الشرقي/النزهة",35.86408,"حكومية",32.54847);
        closeDB();

        //SCHOOL-9
        openDB();
        db.insertSchool("مدرسة القادسية","0795527721","لا يوجد",1981,"لا يوجد","لا يوجد","ممتازة","مختبر حاسوب - مختبر علوم","لا يوجد","اربد/الحي الشرقي",35.86587,"حكومية",32.54785);
        closeDB();

        //SCHOOL-10
        openDB();
        db.insertSchool("مدرسة رقية بنت الرسول الأساسية للبنات","لا يوجد","لا يوجد",1970,"لا يوجد","لا يوجد","لا يوجد","لا يوجد","لا يوجد","لا يوجد",35.85827,"خاصة",32.55319);
        closeDB();

        //SCHOOL-11
        openDB();
        db.insertSchool("مدرسة الإيمان التعليمية","07277323","Math - Science",1996,"الروضة - التاسع","الشراء من مستودع التربية","ممتازة","لا يوجد","الروضة / 850 | الاول - التاسع /1000","اربد/حي الشيخ خليل/مبنى راتب البطاينة",35.85887,"حكومية",32.54622);
        closeDB();



    }



    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////





    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        closeDB();

    }// end onDestroy method



    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



    private void openDB() {
        db = new DBAdapter(this);
        db.open();
    } // end openDB method

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    private void closeDB() {
        db.close();
    } // end closeDB method

}
```

I used a custom list view to retrieve schools names but I got error at run time and the data not added, the following is the database class:

```
public class DBAdapter  {

    private static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";

    //columns names users
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "id";
    public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    public static final String KEY_PASSWD = "passwd";
    public static final String KEY_ADMIN = "isAdmin";
    public static final String KEY_U_PHONE = "phone";

    // School Table Columns names
    public static final String KEY_SCHOOLID = "schoolID";
    public static final String KEY_SCHOOLNAME = "schoolName";
    public static final String KEY_PHONE_NUM = "schoolPhone";
    public static final String KEY_MATERIALS = "schoolExtraM";
    public static final String KEY_FOUNDATION_DATE = "schoolFD";
    public static final String KEY_CLASSES = "schoolClasses";
    public static final String KEY_BUY_BOOKS = "schoolGetBooks";
    public static final String KEY_HEALTH = "schoolHealthSituation";
    public static final String KEY_LABORATORIES = "schoolLabs";
    public static final String KEY_LOCATION = "schoolLocation";
    public static final String KEY_FEES = "schoolFees";
    public static final String KEY_LATITUDE = "schoolLatitude";
    public static final String KEY_LONGITUDE = "schoolLongitude";
    public static final String KEY_SChOOL_TYPE = "schoolType";


    //columns numbers - users
    public static final int COL_ROWID_TABLE_1 = 0;
    public static final int COL_NAME_TABLE_1 = 1;
    public static final int COL_PASSWD_TABLE_1 = 2;
    public static final int COL_ADMIN_TABLE_1 = 3;
    public static final int COL_PHONE_NUM_TABLE_1 = 4;

    //columns numbers - schools
    public static final int COL_SCHOOLID_TABLE_2 = 0;
    public static final int COL_SCHOOLNAME_TABLE_2 = 1;
    public static final int COL_PHONE_NUM_TABLE_2 = 2;
    public static final int COL_MATERIALS_TABLE_2 = 3;
    public static final int COL_FOUNDATION_DATE_TABLE_2 = 4;
    public static final int COL_CLASSES_TABLE_2 = 5;
    public static final int COL_BUY_BOOKS_TABLE_2 = 6;
    public static final int COL_HEALTH_TABLE_2 = 7;
    public static final int COL_LABORATORIES_TABLE_2 = 8;
    public static final int COL_LOCATION_TABLE_2 = 9;
    public static final int COL_FEES_TABLE_2 = 10;
    public static final int COL_LATITUDE_TABLE_2 = 11;
    public static final int COL_LONGITUDE_TABLE_2 = 12;
    public static final int COL_SChOOL_TYPE_TABLE_2 = 13;



    // array for the columns names
    public static final String[] ALL_KEYS_TABLE_1 = new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_PASSWD, KEY_ADMIN,KEY_U_PHONE};

    public static final String[] ALL_KEYS_TABLE_2 = new String[] {KEY_SCHOOLID, KEY_SCHOOLNAME, KEY_PHONE_NUM, KEY_MATERIALS,KEY_FOUNDATION_DATE,KEY_CLASSES,KEY_BUY_BOOKS,KEY_HEALTH,KEY_LABORATORIES,KEY_LOCATION,KEY_FEES,KEY_LATITUDE,KEY_LONGITUDE,KEY_SChOOL_TYPE};

    // the database name and the table name
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MyDb";
    public static final String DATABASE_TABLE_1 = "users";
    public static final String DATABASE_TABLE_2 = "schools";
    // version 
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 8;

    // create table query
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_SQL_1 =
            "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE_1
                    + "("
                    + KEY_ROWID + " integer primary key autoincrement,"
                    + KEY_NAME+ " text not null,"
                    + KEY_PASSWD + " text not null,"
                    +KEY_ADMIN  + " integer not null,"
                    + KEY_U_PHONE  + " text not null"  + ")";

    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_SQL_2 =
            "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE_2
                    + "("
                    + KEY_SCHOOLID + " integer primary key autoincrement,"
                    + KEY_SCHOOLNAME + " text not null,"
                    + KEY_PHONE_NUM + " text not null,"
                    + KEY_MATERIALS + " text not null,"
                    + KEY_FOUNDATION_DATE + " integer not null,"
                    + KEY_CLASSES + " text not null,"
                    + KEY_BUY_BOOKS + " text not null,"
                    + KEY_HEALTH + " text not null,"
                    + KEY_LABORATORIES + " text not null,"
                    + KEY_FEES + " text not null,"
                    + KEY_LOCATION + " text not null,"
                    + KEY_LONGITUDE + " double not null,"
                    + KEY_SChOOL_TYPE + " text not null,"
                    + KEY_LATITUDE + " double not null"  + ")";



    private final Context context;

    // initiates instances from class DatabaseHelper and SQLiteDatabase 
    private DatabaseHelper myDBHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase db; // database


    // constructor
    public DBAdapter(Context ctx) {


        this.context = ctx;
        myDBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);

    }


    public DBAdapter open() {
        db = myDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }


    public void close() {
        myDBHelper.close();
    }


    public long insertSchool(String name, String phone,String materials, int fDate,String classes,String books,String health,String labs,String fees,String location,double longitude,String type,double latitude) {

        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(KEY_NAME, name);
        initialValues.put(KEY_PHONE_NUM,phone);
        initialValues.put(KEY_MATERIALS, materials);
        initialValues.put(KEY_FOUNDATION_DATE, fDate);
        initialValues.put(KEY_CLASSES, classes);
        initialValues.put(KEY_BUY_BOOKS, books);
        initialValues.put(KEY_HEALTH,health);
        initialValues.put(KEY_LABORATORIES, labs);
        initialValues.put(KEY_FEES, fees);
        initialValues.put(KEY_LOCATION, location);
        initialValues.put(KEY_LONGITUDE, longitude);
        initialValues.put(KEY_SChOOL_TYPE, type);
        initialValues.put(KEY_LATITUDE, latitude);


        return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE_2, null, initialValues);
    }

    public long insertUser(String name, String passwd,int isAdmin, String phone) {

        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(KEY_NAME, name);
        initialValues.put(KEY_PASSWD, passwd);
        initialValues.put(KEY_ADMIN, isAdmin);
        initialValues.put(KEY_U_PHONE, phone);


        return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE_1, null, initialValues);
    }


    public boolean deleteShool(String schoolName) {
        String where = KEY_SCHOOLNAME + "='" + schoolName + "'";
        return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE_2, where, null) != 0;
    }


        public boolean deleteSchoolById(long rowId) {
            String where = KEY_SCHOOLID + "=" + rowId;
            return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE_2, where, null) != 0;
        }

    public void deleteAll() {
        Cursor c = getAllRows();
        long rowId = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(KEY_SCHOOLID);
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                deleteSchoolById(c.getLong((int) rowId));
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
        c.close();
    }


    public Cursor getAllRows() {
        String where = null;
        Cursor c =  db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE_2, ALL_KEYS_TABLE_2,
                            where, null, null, null, null, null);
        if (c != null) {
            c.moveToFirst();
        }
        return c;
    }


    public Cursor getAllUsersRows() {
        String where = null;
        Cursor c =  db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE_1, ALL_KEYS_TABLE_1,
                where, null, null, null, null, null);
        if (c != null) {
            c.moveToFirst();
        }
        return c;
    }


    public Cursor getRow(long rowId) {
        String where = KEY_SCHOOLID+ "=" + rowId;
        Cursor c =  db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE_2, ALL_KEYS_TABLE_2,
                        where, null, null, null, null, null);
        if (c != null) {
            c.moveToFirst();
        }
        return c;
    }



    public Cursor getRowByName(String name) {
        String where = KEY_SCHOOLNAME + "='" + name+"'";
        Cursor c =  db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE_2, ALL_KEYS_TABLE_2,
                        where, null, null, null, null, null);
        if (c != null) {
            c.moveToFirst();
        }
        return c;
    }



    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
    {
        DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase _db) {

            _db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_SQL_1);
            _db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_SQL_2);


        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase _db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading application's database from version " + oldVersion
                    + " to " + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data!");


             _db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE_1);
            _db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE_2);


            onCreate(_db);



        }


    }



}
```

LOG:

```
 --------- beginning of /dev/log/main
  android.view.ViewConfiguration.getScaledHorizontalScrollFactor, referenced from method android.support.v4.view.ViewConfigurationCompat.getScaledHorizontalScrollFactor
04-11 10:53:36.018 2231-2231/com.example.welcome.madrasti W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 21145: Landroid/view/ViewConfiguration;.getScaledHorizontalScrollFactor ()F
04-11 10:53:36.018 2231-2231/com.example.welcome.madrasti D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
04-11 10:53:36.018 2231-2231/com.example.welcome.madrasti I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.ViewConfiguration.getScaledVerticalScrollFactor, referenced from method android.support.v4.view.ViewConfigurationCompat.getScaledVerticalScrollFactor
04-11 10:53:36.018 2231-2231/com.example.welcome.madrasti W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 21150: Landroid/view/ViewConfiguration;.getScaledVerticalScrollFactor ()F
04-11 10:53:36.018 2231-2231/com.example.welcome.madrasti D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
04-11 10:53:36.050 2231-2231/com.example.welcome.madrasti E/SQLiteLog: (1) table schools has no column named name
04-11 10:53:36.050 2231-2231/com.example.welcome.madrasti E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting schoolFees=480 - 550 schoolLocation=اربد/مجمع الشيخ خليل/حي النزهة schoolLatitude=32.54845 schoolLabs=مختبر حاسوب - مختبر علوم schoolPhone=0797417018 - 0790889165 name=مدرسة دار المعرفة schoolExtraM=Math - Science schoolLongitude=35.85542 schoolClasses=الأول - السابع schoolType=خاصة schoolHealthSituation=جيدة جدا schoolFD=2009 schoolGetBooks=عن طريق مستودع التربية
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table schools has no column named name (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO schools(schoolFees,schoolLocation,schoolLatitude,schoolLabs,schoolPhone,name,schoolExtraM,schoolLongitude,schoolClasses,schoolType,schoolHealthSituation,schoolFD,schoolGetBooks) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1467)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1339)
        at com.example.welcome.madrasti.DBAdapter.insertSchool(DBAdapter.java:152)
        at com.example.welcome.madrasti.MainActivity.insertSchools(MainActivity.java:172)
        at com.example.welcome.madrasti.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:51)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-11 10:53:36.054 2231-2231/com.example.welcome.madrasti E/SQLiteLog: (1) table schools has no column named name
04-11 10:53:36.058 2231-2231/com.example.welcome.madrasti E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting schoolFees=روضة / 500 | الاول - ثاني ثنوي / 1100 schoolLocation=اربد/شارع الحصن/بجانب اسواق مكة schoolLatitude=32.55172 schoolLabs=مختبر حاسوب - مختبر علوم - مكتبة - فرقة فن schoolPhone=07272881 name=مدرسة الروم الكاثوليك schoolExtraM=فرنسي schoolLongitude=35.85155 schoolClasses=بستان - ثاني ثانوي schoolType=خاصة schoolHealthSituation=ممتازة schoolFD=1951 schoolGetBooks=الشراء من مستودع التربية
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table schools has no column named name (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO schools(schoolFees,schoolLocation,schoolLatitude,schoolLabs,schoolPhone,name,schoolExtraM,schoolLongitude,schoolClasses,schoolType,schoolHealthSituation,schoolFD,schoolGetBooks) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1467)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1339)
        at com.example.welcome.madrasti.DBAdapter.insertSchool(DBAdapter.java:152)
        at com.example.welcome.madrasti.MainActivity.insertSchools(MainActivity.java:176)
        at com.example.welcome.madrasti.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:51)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-11 10:53:36.062 2231-2231/com.example.welcome.madrasti E/SQLiteLog: (1) t
```

I do not know why the rows are not inserted in the database, any help please!?! is Arabic language is the reason?

Comment: What is the error your are getting ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without actually testing the code, it looks to me like you just have a minor typo causing the bug. You create your `schools` table with the column name `KEY_SCHOOLNAME` (defined as `schoolName`), but in your `insertSchool` method you appear to have `initialValues.put(KEY_NAME, name);`, which uses the column name `name` from the users table. I think if you just change that line in `insertSchool` to `initialValues.put(KEY_SCHOOLNAME, name);` it will fix your error.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is datatype error. fDate is integer and I think ContentValues need both key and value String.

```
initialValues.put(KEY_FOUNDATION_DATE, ""+fDate);
```

Comment: This not correct, ContentValues actually works with most basic datatypes: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentValues.html#put(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Long).